# How do i use gdal2tiles for creating tilecache?

Tags: python, gdal, tiles, tilecache, gdal2tiles

I want to create tiled cache from raster file, so i downloaded gdal2tiles.py.
Now i don't get what (and how) i must do with that python script file.

Comment: Have you checked its documentation or --help output?

Comment: Google search gave me: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/Gdal2Tiles and http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2008/03/generating-map-tiles-with-gdal2tiles.html and

Answer (score 1):

The following would create fixed size tiles of your_raster_file in the directory /tmp/test

```
gdal_retile.py -ps 512 512 -targetDir /tmp/test your_raster_file.tif
```